# Проверить есть ли ссылка в строке

Tags: php

Есть вводимое поле textarea. В поле вводим ссылку с текстом. Передаем на сервер PHP post запросом. Принимаем эту строку. И вот задача, как проверить есть ли в этой строке ссылка типа "http://www.google.ru/" или "www.google.ru".?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать RegEx

```
(http(s)?://.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

[Тест](http://regexr.com/39i0i)

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: и проверять регулярку через preg_match()?

Comment: Да, через `preg_match()`

Answer (score -2):

Если известна строка поиска, то не проще ли использовать:

```
strpos($string, 'www.google.ru')
```

Comment: Строка типа != известная строка